# How to send a data payload of a size 1 MB or greater with MAM and node.js?

Tags: iota-network, tangle, masked-authenticated-messaging, javascript, hornet

I know MAM is deprecated but I am doing some research on MAM. I was able to send and fetch a data payload of size 740 KB. But when I tried to use a data of 1 MB I am getting this issue with node.js

Node.js displays
fatal runtime error: Allocator memory exhausted
trap!
trap!

I even tried to increase the --max-old-space parameter but it did not work. I am using JSON datasets and a private tangle of 3 nodes.

Will splitting the data into fragments work? If so, then how do I do that and send them to the tangle using MAM?

Please help someone. I have attached images of my MAM code here.[image][image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Splitting the data into fragments will work. Alternatively if you work with the IOTA streams library you should have more luck with big sizes.

https://github.com/iotaledger/streams